# I'm trying to get the output from my for loop to print in a single line in the console

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, printing, console

```js
var n = Number(Math.ceil(Math.random()*10));
console.log(n);
var newN= n-1;  
var counter = 1;

while(counter <=  n){  
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
     console.log(newN);
    }
    
    newN+=2;
    counter++;
}
```

And it must look like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console.log always do a new line so create a string and concat with the digit N times and then print it like this:

```
var n = Number(Math.ceil(Math.random()*10));
console.log(n);
var newN= n-1;  
var counter = 1;

while(counter <=  n){  
  let str = ''
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
   str = str + newN
  }
  console.log(str)

  newN+=2;
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just built a string for each line and then `console.log` it when done.

```
var s = '';

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
  s += newN + '\t';
}

console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
console.log(n);

for(let count = 1; count < n; count++)
   console.log(("" + (n - 1 + count * 2)).repeat(n));
```

You could simply use *repeat* to print it *n* times in a row.